# ajax - php upload multiple files and show previously uploaded files

Tags: php, ajax

Html form

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
 <input name="files[]" type="file" id="upload_file" /><br/>
 <input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload File" />
 </form>
```

Then with ajax send to php

```
$("#upload_file").hide();
$("#upload").click(function() {
$("#upload_file").click();
})

$('#upload_file').change(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var formData = new FormData($(this).parents('form')[0]);

$.ajax({
url: '___ajax_upload_files.php',
type: 'POST',
xhr: function() {
var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
return myXhr;
},
success: function (data) {

$('#upload_span').html( data );
},
data: formData,
cache: false,
contentType: false,
processData: false
});
return false;
})
```

Then process in php like here (actual code is a bit different)

```
if ( !empty( $_FILES['files']['name'] ) ) {
$target_path = '../images/';
$ext = explode('.', basename( $_FILES['files']['name'] ) );
$target_path = $target_path . md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext[count($ext)-1]; 
$val_img = substr( $target_path , 10 );

//Here code to display uploaded image

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) {
echo '<a href=""><img src="../images/'. $val_img. '" ></a> ';
}

}
```

Problem is that on each `$('#upload_file').change(function(e) {` uploads a new file and `echo '<a href=""><img src="../images/'. $val_img. '" ></a> ';` only the newly uploaded file. But how to echo also previosly uploaded files?

At the moment think that need either session or fetch from mysql. 
Like foreach session or mysql data

`echo '<a href=""><img src="../images/'. $session_or_mysql_val_img. '" ></a> ';`

I mean: user opens page, clicks Upload; uploads first, second etc. files and sees all the uploaded files (now can see only last uploaded file).

Any better solution?

Comment: That's pretty nasty code. you simply ASSUME uploads will never fail, and don't do any kind of validation on the uploads.

Comment: I will write code for validation. At the moment aim is to show all uploaded files.

Comment: Regarding validation i am trying to follow these advices http://www.tidy-designs.co.uk/website-development/php-secure-file-upload-script/ , https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unrestricted_File_Upload , http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/csrf-attacks/